# Images added to drawable folder not being recognized when the getFields() method is run

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have added 720 new images to my `Drawable` folder, but none of them are being recognized when I use `Field[] drawables = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();` .

```
Field[] drawables = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();
    for (Field f : drawables) {
        try {
            System.out.println("R.drawable." + f.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This just returns a list of the images added by default to the `Drawable` folder. I also tried `getDeclaredFields` but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use your own generated R class, that's `your.package.name.R.drawable`.

Comment: Why is this answer hidden so deep?