# Android dynamically load gif from drawable directory

Tags: android-studio, android-drawable

I am using `Recycler View`. I have some gif in drawable. I have an integer list `List<Integer> images`, I want to store the `ids` of the gif in this list.

I got the names of the `gif` from the below code:

```
Field[] drawables = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();
        for (Field f : drawables) {
            try {
                int iconResId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(f.getName(),"drawable",this.getPackageName());
                images.add(iconResId);
              
               
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But it is not working, it is not showing me any images. I am sure that the rest of the code is ok, because if i manually add the name of any gif i.e. `images.add(R.drawable.gif_name)` then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, when I tried to debug it, using

```
Log.d(MainPage.class.getName(), "The name is " + f.getName());
```

There I found that, it doesn't show the names of the gif in drawable directory, it shows the names of default images only. After some search I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41595909/9235408).

Show I have to use my own generated R class, i.e. `my_package_name.R.drawable.class.getFields()`, instead of  `android.R.drawable.class.getFields()`.